# Telerik LineSeries DataPoint Circle

Tags: android, charts, telerik

I have a `LineSeries`

```
RadCartesianChartView chart = new RadCartesianChartView(context);

CartesianChartGrid cartesianChartGrid = new CartesianChartGrid();
cartesianChartGrid.setMajorYLinesRenderMode(GridLineRenderMode.INNER_AND_LAST);
cartesianChartGrid.setMajorXLinesRenderMode(GridLineRenderMode.INNER_AND_LAST);
cartesianChartGrid.setLineThickness(1);
cartesianChartGrid.setLineColor(Color.CYAN);
chart.setGrid(cartesianChartGrid);
LineSeries series = new LineSeries();

series.setStrokeColor(Color.GRAY);
```

But line is shown continuous without any point denoting the data point.
How can I show circles as data points on line.

Answer (score 0):

To show the data points you have to add some methods in series.

```
series.setShowLabels(true);
```

And in case you need you can format labels in any java format you need

```
series.setLabelFormat("%.0f");
```

Hope it helps